# CSS specificity and !important

Tags: css

I think I have a wrong understanding of how specificity and !important works .

Consider the below HTML :

```
 <head>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style1.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
  <body>
     <div  class = "outer">
        <div class = "inner1">
            <div class = "inner2">
                <p>Voluptate labore cupidatat an enim quamquam ut anim malis, varias id sed veniam 
                    quibusdam, singulis aliqua ut singulis domesticarum, id aliqua illum o officia, 
                    et ab domesticarum, irure e excepteur o eram nam appellat coniunctione do 
                    commodo..</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

STYLE.CSS

```
.outer .inner1  {
    color:green !important;
}
```

STYLE1.CSS

```
.outer .inner1 .inner2 {
    color:red ;

}
```

My understanding was the rule in style.css will never be overwritten (as it has an important tag) even though the rule in syle1.css has more specificity . 
I was thinking rules are applied as they are encountered in the HTML file ( style.css first and then style1.css) , and a value for a particular property of an element will be overwritten only if the rule is more specific ( important tag prevents this overriding no matter how specific the subsequent rule is ) . This apparently is not how it works . Could someone tell me how does !important and specificity work and when do you use !important ?

Comment: Specifity overrides inherited rules even with !important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Styles for a directly targeted element will always take precedence over inherited styles, regardless of the specificity of the inherited rule.*

-- [**Specificity: Directly targeted elements vs. inherited styles**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#Directly_targeted_elements_vs._inherited_styles)

---

**Note:** the addition of the new contrived ruleset in Demo:

```
div.outer.outer.outer>div.inner1>div.inner2.inner2>aside.inner3 {
  color: blue !important
}
```

It has an incredibly ridiculously unnecessarily huge specificity score of 0,0,7,4 and !important as well. CSS reads from right to left:

1. Find an `<aside>` tag with the class of `.inner3`
2. It must have a parent `<div>` that has the class of `.inner2`.
3. Also that `<div class="inner2">`must have a parent `<div>` with a class of `.inner1`.
4. And it's imperative that `<div class="inner1">` have a parent `<div>` with the class of `.outer`.

All of these specific rules of the selector must be met just so a deeply nested `<aside>` tag gets its style. Any descendant elements of `.inner3` will inherit `color: blue` property and value, but it is easily overridden by the likes of `i.inner2` with `color:red`.

```
   <div class="inner3">
     <p>This deeply nested text has <i class='inner2'>crazy specificity but this text is red.</i>
       ...
     </p>
   </div>
```

**Note:** the new ruleset at the bottom of CSS box:

```
  div {
    color: black !important
  }
```

Now this selector is specific to ***all divs*** so here is how `!important` has just been assigned a selector with a far reaching scope. This is probably more like the behavior you were expecting.

---

BTW, you probably noticed the duplicate classes:

```
  .outer.outer.outer
```

That is called selector chaining which will increase a selector's specificity score. See **[Online Specificity Calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/)**.

---

### Demo

---

```css
div.outer.outer.outer>div.inner1>div.inner2.inner2>aside.inner3 {
  color: blue !important
}

.outer .inner1 {
  color: green !important;
}

.outer .inner1 .inner2 {
  color: red;
}

div {
  color:black !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style1.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner1">
      This text will be green...
      <div class="inner2">
        <p>Voluptate labore cupidatat an enim quamquam ut anim malis, varias id sed veniam quibusdam, singulis aliqua ut singulis domesticarum, id aliqua illum o officia, et ab domesticarum, irure e excepteur o eram nam appellat coniunctione do commodo..
        </p>

        <aside class='inner3'>
          <p>This deeply nested text has <i class='inner1'>crazy specificity</i>, yet it only applies to it and its descendants with no specific <b class='inner2'>`color` property</b>.</p>
        </aside>
      </div>
      ...and this text will be green as well.
    </div>
  </div>
```